After removing outliers using IQR technique I visualized the data with a boxplot but it still shows outliers. How can I confirm outliers were removed?
The 'mmr' column in my dataset contains car prices and I want to identify outliers in this column. First I visualized the data using a boxplot, which shows the presence of outliers.
Visualisation of the mmr column
What I did was to use the IQR column, I calculated the 25th percentile and the 75th percentile, for me to calculate the upper limit and lower limit of the column and the filter the data to show the rows which were identified as outliers. steps shown on code below:
# Calculating Q1, Q3, and IQR
Q1 = np.percentile(df['mmr'],25)
Q3 = np.percentile(df['mmr'],75)
IQR = Q3- Q1

#defining outlier thresholds
lower_bound = Q1 - 1.5 * IQR
upper_bound = Q3 + 1.5 * IQR

# filtering to show rows that contain outliers
df[(df['mmr']< lower_bound) | (df['mmr'] > upper_bound)]


I then filtered out the outliers, leaving only the values within the required range and visualised the data:
dfNoOutlier = df[(df['mmr'] > lower_bound) & (df['mmr'] < upper_bound)]
plt.boxplot(dfNoOutlier['mmr'])


Output after removing outliers
The boxplot shows that there are outliers remaining how can solve that?
